# ionic 4 - Uncaught TypeError when add plugin

Tags: ionic4

I have created an ionic project(version: 4.0.6). I am getting below error after adding the plugin cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing from  https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing.
I am stuck here. Could anybody help me on this please.

```
index.js:413 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:413
    at Object../node_modules/@ionic-native/social-sharing/index.js (index.js:590)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.global.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/main.ts (environment.ts:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:43)
```

Update: I found one solution today! 
step1: change version of plugin in package.json to the same version of @ionic-native/core that shown in the package.json. 
Step 2: remove node_module and run npm install. 
Step 3: add '/ngx' at the end when import it like below;
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
step 4: do rest same as ionic 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

The Angular versions are now imported from `@ionic-native/plugin-xxx/ngx`.