# ionic-framework ios build fails | socialsharing | appversion

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

i have this problem when try to build iOS in Ionic pro service.

this is the output:

```
[14:05:26]: ▸ > GlamitApp@0.0.1 build /builds/project-0
[14:05:26]: ▸ > ionic-app-scripts build --buildConfig=build.json
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.2 
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  build dev started ...
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  clean started ...
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  clean finished in 4 ms
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  copy started ...
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  deeplinks started ...
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  deeplinks finished in 229 ms
[14:05:28]: ▸ [14:05:28]  transpile started ...
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  typescript: src/app/app.component.ts, line: 51 
[14:05:33]: ▸ Cannot find name 'SocialSharing'.
[14:05:33]: ▸       L50:    public events: Events,
[14:05:33]: ▸       L51:    private socialSharing: SocialSharing
[14:05:33]: ▸       L52:  ) {
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  typescript: src/app/app.module.ts, line: 64 
[14:05:33]: ▸ Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof ChatPage | typeof RatePage | typeof DetallePedidoPage | typeof
[14:05:33]: ▸ HistorialP...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are
[14:05:33]: ▸ incompatible. Type '(typeof SplashScreen | SocialSharingOriginal | typeof UserProvider | typeof InAppBrowser
[14:05:33]: ▸ | AppVer...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof SplashScreen | SocialSharingOriginal |
[14:05:33]: ▸ typeof UserProvider | typeof InAppBrowser | AppVers...' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type
[14:05:33]: ▸ 'SocialSharingOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'SocialSharingOriginal' is not assignable
[14:05:33]: ▸ to type 'ClassProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing in type 'SocialSharingOriginal'.
[14:05:33]: ▸       L64:  @NgModule({                                                                                                                                                
[14:05:33]: ▸       L65:    declarations: [
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  typescript: src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 41 
[14:05:33]: ▸ Cannot find name 'AppVersion'.
[14:05:33]: ▸       L40:  public events: Events,
[14:05:33]: ▸       L41:  private appVersion: AppVersion) {
[14:05:33]: ▸       L42:  localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  typescript: src/pages/my-profile/my-profile.ts, line: 30 
[14:05:33]: ▸ Cannot find name 'AppVersion'.
[14:05:33]: ▸       L29:  public platform: Platform,
[14:05:33]: ▸       L30:  private appVersion: AppVersion) {
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[14:05:33]: ▸ [14:05:33]  Error: Failed to transpile program 
[14:05:33]: ▸ Error: Failed to transpile program
[14:05:33]: ▸     at new BuildError (/builds/project-0/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
[14:05:33]: ▸     at /builds/project-0/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
[14:05:33]: ▸     at new Promise ()
[14:05:33]: ▸     at transpileWorker (/builds/project-0/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
[14:05:33]: ▸     at Object.transpile (/builds/project-0/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
[14:05:33]: ▸     at /builds/project-0/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
[14:05:33]: ▸     at 
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! errno 1
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! GlamitApp@0.0.1 build: `ionic-app-scripts build --buildConfig=build.json`
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! Exit status 1
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR!
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! Failed at the GlamitApp@0.0.1 build script.
[14:05:33]: ▸ npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

SocialSharing and AppVersion are added correctly in the project,
always build and compile ok, but now i have this errors.

The problem is this components o another thing?

Anyone can help me? I need to solve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm was facing circular dependency issues with the Social Sharing plugin as well. I have not used the plugin in a while and it seems the `@ionic-native/social-sharing` package now exports the class `SocialSharingOriginal` and not the usual `SocialSharing`. Have not found any change logs so far highlighting the breaking change, which is perhaps for `Ionic 4`.

So far a workaround is to import the `SocialSharing` class as below.

```
import { SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
```

and don't forget to revert your `constructor` declarations and `app.module.ts` imports to `SocialSharing`.

Comment: thanks so much, i solved adding /ngx to imports.
Really Ionic 4 changes some thins. How do you know this??

This post helpss me too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856853/ionic-4-uncaught-typeerror-when-add-plugin

Comment: I looked at the source code of the `@ionic-native/social-sharing` package. Previous experience told me something was wrong when the `SocialSharing` import wasn't working as expected. Especially with a good editor like VSCode you can get a good idea of what may be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a syntax error.

Could you check is the closing bracket intentional of Line no 52.

```
Cannot find name 'SocialSharing'.
[14:05:33]: ▸       L50:    public events: Events,
[14:05:33]: ▸       L51:    private socialSharing: SocialSharing
[14:05:33]: ▸       L52:  ) {
```

If this is not a problem then do let me know, might need more information to understand the issue.

Comment: this is intentional, its constructor closing ')'. Its not a problem with the syntax.

Comment: what's the social-sharing version?